# How to do two-level boxplots, with the whiskers redefined in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'd like to make a boxplot with two different factors:

```
df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
                  f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("young","old")),
                  boxthis=rnorm(100))

ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + geom_boxplot()
```

I'd also like to redefine the whiskers based on quantiles:

```
f <- function(x) {
  r <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.975))
  names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
  r
}

ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + stat_summary(fun.data = f, geom="boxplot")
```

However, when using stat_summary(), the two different boxplot at the same location on the x axis are drawn on top of each other, instead of next to each other as when geom_boxplot() is called.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `position="dodge"` to `stat_summary()`. For the `geom_boxplot()` `position="dodge"` is already a default value so you don't have to write it but for `stat_summary()` you have to define this yourself.

```
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = f, geom="boxplot",position="dodge")
```